# Refer to the property of a target in generator expression of custom target

Tags: cmake

CMake version: `3.16.2`

---

I'm trying to write a custom target for CMake, which allows me to get some properties from a known target.

I have this code:

```
add_custom_target(target_printer
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:known_target, BINARY_DIR>"
)
```

On the configuration step, I faced the next problem:

```
Error evaluating generator expression:
 $<TARGET_PROPERTY:known_target, BINARY_DIR>

Property name not supported.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: As far as I know, a space (`' '`) is not a valid character in the generator expression. Try `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:known_target,BINARY_DIR>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using generator expressions to retrieve one of the properties of a CMake target, CMake first *verifies* that the requested property is valid. During this verification, CMake will check to see if the provided property `BINARY_DIR` is a well-formed CMake property via regular expressions. It is a valid property, but the verification fails because of the extra space provided next to the property name. Generator expressions have very *specific* syntax (relevant example [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#string-transformations)), and in this case, spaces are **not** permitted surrounding the property name `BINARY_DIR`. Try removing the extra space before `BINARY_DIR`:

```
add_custom_target(target_printer
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:known_target,BINARY_DIR>"
)
```